# can LAN port have multiple IP addresses of same subnet mask or different subnet mask

Tags: router, subnet, ip-address, lan, interface

Can the router's ethernet interface have multiple IP's of the same subnet or different subnet mask?

If yes what's the use?

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

> Can the router's ethernet interface have multiple IPs of the same subnet

Generally yes, but that may be be limited by the system.

> or different subnet mask?

No, not if there's overlap. E.g. `192.168.0.1/24` *and* `192.168.0.129/25` simultaneously aren't possible because they overlap. `192.168.0.1/24` and `192.168.0.129/24` (same subnet), or `192.168.0.1/24` and `192.168.1.129/25` (distinct subnets) *are* generally possible.

Overlapping subnets make no sense on a single interface and normally cannot even be configured. Different subnet masks (prefix lengths) *are* possible for different subnets, however, e.g. `192.168.0.1/24` and `10.0.1.0/16`.

> what's the use?

One use is with NAT, when multiple public IP addresses are mapped across the same router and usually forwarded differently. Another use is with services bound to specific IP addresses and using different default gateways. Also, if you're renumbering your network you often use multiple IP addresses for key devices temporarily and route between them.

Note that while multiple *IPv4* addresses are not that common, *IPv6* uses multiple addresses routinely (link-local, unique-local, global, ...), even of the same type. For instance, you can slowly phase out a changing global prefix while phasing in the new one at the same time.

Comment: Yah but u didn't explain why can't we assign another ip from same subnet mask like 192.168.1.5 and 172.168.1.3?

Comment: @Rohit By networking standards, you can assign multiple IP addresses from the same subnet or from any other to a single host NIC - I've done that quite a few times. A given host might not allow that but what hosts do or don't do is explicitly off-topic here, see the [help].

Comment: so can we say that in IP aliasing we can add multiple ip address from same and different subnet mask?

Comment: @Rohit Wouldn't call that "aliasing" though. As noted in the answer, you can't have overlapping subnets but anything else.

Comment: But in this video https://youtu.be/if0OM5-Sd0c he is using same subnet mask why?

Comment: And last doubt sir let's take for example if I assign my nic ip from 192.168.1.0/24 then why can't we have secondary address 172.168.1.0/24??pls explain???

Comment: Neither IP address is a valid host address, with all host bits zero. OTOH, 192.168.1.1/24 and 172.16.1.1/24 on the same NIC shouldn't be a problem. 172.168.1.0/24 isn't part of any private address range, see RFC 1918. It belongs to AOL.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129259/discussion-between-rohit-and-zac67).

Answer (score 0):

Juniper router allows multiple IP addresses from the same subnet to be configured on an interface. However, practically only one is chosen to be the primary:

[Configuring the Preferred Address for an Interface:](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/us/en/software/junos/interfaces-fundamentals/topics/topic-map/protocol-family-interface-address-properties.html)

The preferred address on an interface is the default local address used for packets sourced by the local router to destinations on the subnet. By default, the numerically lowest local address is chosen. For example, if the addresses 172.16.1.1/12, 172.16.1.2/12, and 172.16.1.3/12 are configured on the same interface, the preferred address on the subnet (by default, 172.16.1.1) would be used as a local address when you issue a ping 172.16.1.5 command.